# How to pass parameter in js function call inside anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

**This is my ajax call:**

```
$.ajax({                                      
    url: 'UserList.jsp',                 
    success: function(val){
        data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val));
        var j=0;
        var len=shareInfoLen = Object.keys(data).length;
        while(j<len){
            if(data[j].user){
                $online.append("<a href='javascript:chatuser("+data[j].user+")'>'"+data[j].user+"'</a>");
            }
            j++;
        }
    },
    error:function(val){
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```

Inside $online.append() when I call chatuser() function with any parameter it return syntax error. Kindly suggest me how can I pass parameter in such condition.

Comment: You're not putting quotes around the appended string to that inline binding.  Also, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val))`, don't do that.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?  (Browser, Inspect Element)

Comment: You say `chatUser()`. But you write `chatuser()`.

Comment: `'javascript:chatuser(\'" + data + "\')'...`

Comment: from `Object.keys(data)` it seems that data is an object while you are accessing items like it's an array. One is wrong

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz you can do Object.keys on an array and it will return the indexes.  It's weird, but not wrong.

Comment: @Taplar You are right but as you said, it's weird

Comment: Sir, I want to pass **data[j].user** as a parameter but it gives an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick test and it worked fine this way. Check my snippet. The main problem was that you were passing the user name with no quotes (javascript will interprete that as a variable).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  /**
   * Dummy data
   */

  var data = [
    { user : 'User 1' },
    { user : 'User 2' }
  ];

  /**
   * Dummy chat user function
   * @param user
   * @param index
   */

  function chatuser(user, index) {
    console.log(user, data[index]);
  }
  
  // Variables
  var j   = 0,
      len = data.length,
      ul  = $('.placeholder');
      
  while(j < len) {
    if(data[j].user) {
      ul.append(jQuery("<li><a href=\"javascript:chatuser('" + data[j].user + "', "+j+");\">" + data[j].user + "</a></li>")); // Pass the user as a string and the current index in the array
    }
    j++;
  }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="placeholder"></ul>
```

I don't know why the function call inside the links isn't invoked in the snippet, but the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of changes in here. Most significant:

- Use `var` to declare your `data` variable so that it doesn't leak onto the global (window) object.
- Use the concept of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to your advantage by creating a function within your success handler that will preserve your `data` array. This function will continue to have access to your array even after the `success` function has exited.
- Pre-process your `data` array to remove unwanted entires and to strip out unnecessary data. Your loop will run faster and your closure variables won't use up as much memory.
- Don't build DOM objects with strings. It's messy and leads to a lot of errors when you forget to escape special characters. Instead, use jQuery's `text` and `attr` functions to handle all of this for you.
- Get rid of the while loop. It's unnecessary when you've got a very handy `forEach` function built right into the array (it also removes extra variables that you didn't need in the first place).

Here's the sample code:

```
$.ajax({                                      
    url: 'UserList.jsp',                 
    success: function(val){
        var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val));
        if ($.isArray(data)){
            // Filter the data array and stip it down to only the data we need
            data = data
                .filter(function(item){ return ( item && item.user ) ? true : false; })
                .map(function(item){ return { user: item.user }; });
        } else {
            data = [];
        }
        data.forEach(function(item){
            $("<a>")
                .text(item.user)
                .click(function(){
                    chatuser(item.user);
                })
                .appendTo($online);
            j++;
        });
    },
    error:function(val){
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```